# How to disable button(s) when another button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I have a GUI calcualtor, and I want to disable the digit buttons when the equal button is pressed.

Here is the HTML for the button which contains the digit 1:

```
<td>
  <button type="button" name="digit" value="1" value2 = "disabled">
    1
  </button>
</td>
```

This is the HTML for the equals button:

```
<button type="button" name="equals" value="=">
  =
</button>
```

Here is my JavaScript code attempting to disable it...

```
document.getElementsByName("equals")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementsByName("digit").disabled = true;
});
```

Why is this not working? The event listener should disable it.

Comment: There are different way you can do it. This is one way: ``<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('digit').disabled=true;" type="submit" class="positive" value="=">

<input type="button" type="submit" class="negative" name="digit" id="digit" value="disabled">``

Comment: And here is another way:    ``<script>
        function DisableDigit() {
            document.getElementById("digit").disabled = true;
        }
    </script> <input type="button" id="button1" value="=" onclick="DisableDigit()"  />
    <input type="button" id="digit" value="disabled" />``

Comment: Sorry I posted the answer as a comment, but somebody misunderstood your question and marked it as a duplicate, but I see no duplicate in your question. What I understood is that you simply want to disable one button, by the use of another.

Comment: Personally I think this solution is the best since with this one you can add more then one button at the same time to be disabled from just one button click: ``<script type="text/javascript">function DisableButtons() {
            document.getElementById("digit1").disabled = true;
   document.getElementById("digit2").disabled = true;
        } </script> <input type="button" id="button1" value="=" onclick="DisableButtons()" /> <input type="button" id="digit1" value="disabled" /><input type="button" id="digit2" value="disabled2" />``

Answer (score 0):

**[document.getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)** returns a [**NodeList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) **collection** of elements.

Instead of `document.getElementsByName("digit")`, you're looking for `document.getElementsByName("digit")[0]` in order to access the first element in that collection.

```js
document.getElementsByName("equals")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementsByName("digit")[0].disabled = true;
});
```

```html
<td>
  <button type="button" name="digit" value="1" value2="disabled">
    1
  </button>
</td>

<button type="button" name="equals" value="=">
  =
</button>
```

Hope this helps! :)